# Arquillian and Tomcat6 issue

Tags: tomcat6, jboss-arquillian

I have two questions regarding Arquillian and Tomcat:

-My arquillian tests fail with the following error message:

> org.jboss.jsfunit.example.hellojsf.HelloJSFTest  Time elapsed: 0 sec 
>   <<< ERROR! org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.ConfigurationException:
>   Unable to connect to Tomcat manager. The server command
>   (/deploy?path=%2Ftest) failed with responseCode (401) and
>   responseMessage (Non-Autorisé). Please make sure that you provided
>   correct credentials to an user which is able to access Tomcat manager
>   application. These credentials can be specified in the Arquillian
>   container configuration as "user" and "pass" properties. The user must
>   have appripriate role specified in tomcat-users.xml file.

FYI my arquillian.xml file is as follows:

```
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian-1.0.xsd">
      <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
         <property name="jmxPort">8099</property>
        <property name="user">admin</property>
        <property name="pass">admin75</property>
    </engine>

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 2.5" />
     <container qualifier="tomcat-remote">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jmxPort">8099</property>
            <property name="user">admin</property>
            <property name="pass">admin75</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

I am trying to adapt the sample app for tomcat 6. Can anyone please help?

-When will Arquillian support tomcat 7?

Regards,

J.

tomcat-users.xml:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin75" roles="manager,admin"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 2):

This message

> Unable to connect to Tomcat manager. The server command (/deploy?path=%2Ftest) failed with responseCode (401) and responseMessage (Non-Autorisé).

indicates that one of the following is true:

- the `tomcat-users.xml` file used by your Tomcat installation does not have the `admin` user (that you've specified in `arquillian.xml`),
- or the `admin` user is not mapped to the `manager` role in Tomcat 6, or the `manager-script` role in Tomcat 7.

> When will Arquillian support tomcat 7?

Arquillian supports Tomcat 7, as an emebedded or a managed container. The documentation is not up to date (as of now), but the configuration parameters are more or less the same as the embedded and managed equivalents in Tomcat 6. The artifact Id to use for

- a managed Tomcat 7 instance is `org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-tomcat-managed-7`.
- an embedded Tomcat 7 instance is `org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-tomcat-embedded-7`.

As of today, `1.0.0.CR2` is the latest stable release. You can use `1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT`, if you want to work against the development build.

---

Also, you can omit several redundant properties from your `arquillian.xml` file. A cleaner configuration would look like:

```
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian-1.0.xsd">
      <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
    </engine>

    <container qualifier="tomcat-remote">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jmxPort">8099</property>
            <property name="user">admin</property>
            <property name="pass">admin75</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have checked the security configuration and as you can see for yourself (see my xml above), the config is ok. Where else do I have to look to? Regards, Julien.

Comment: @balteo, can you access the manager application using the same credentials? Arquillian deploys the test by uploading the archive to the `/manager/deploy` URL (like `http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy`). If you fail to access this URL, could you post the message that you receive?

Comment: it seems I can access the url. Here what I get: (ECHEC - Un chemin de contexte invalide null a été spécifié) the pages does load and I don't get a security exception.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is related to [ARQ-630](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-630) and [SHRINKDESC-97](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SHRINKDESC-97) but I can't say for sure. Can you verify whether specifying the workaround specified in SHRINKDESC-97 of specifying `project.build.sourceEncoding` or `argLine` (with `file.encoding`) will change the behavior? You'll need to change the encoding of arquillian.xml to the same encoding that you specify in your project POM, which should be `ISO-8859-1` (since the fix for ARQ-630 is not available in the Nexus repo).

Comment: Hmm, any chance I could get a test case to reproduce this?

Comment: Sure Vineet. Where do I send the .zip file to?

Comment: @balteo, you can upload it into [this JBoss forum thread](http://community.jboss.org/thread/174507?tstart=0) that you've created (I noticed it later).

Comment: I have uploaded the file. Keep me posted if you can't reproduce the bug.